# How to Convert Jsp Page to PDF and how to save it furthur

Tags: jsp, pdf

i am making a Web base Billing System in which firstly i am to get a form filled by User and then need to convert it into a PDF .. I am Using JSP SO What i want to ask is I don't know how to Convert JSP form into Pdf and save that pdf file? please tell me how can i convert that form in pdf and save it into the user's machine.?

Comment: Have you surfed this:http://www.coderanch.com/t/528357/open-source/convert-jsp-form-pdf-file

Comment: I am working With it But tel me what is That PDF Conversion in the Main Function.

public static void main(String args[])    
  
   {    
  
    PDFConversion pdfConversion = new PDFConversion();    
  
    //pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/shunmuga/tajmahal.jpg", "C:/shunmuga/tajmahal.pdf", true);    
  
      
  
 // For other files    
  
     pdfConversion.createPdf("a.html","sample.pdf", false);    
  
    }    
  
 }

Comment: Did you see the whole code? That is the name of the class inside which he has defined the `main()` method!

Comment: oops...!! i didn't Notify that i am very new to coding.. :) 

please tell me one more thing. i am initializing it into a java class so what code should replace this line.its showing a error . 

pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));

Comment: Edit your question, please post your code and the errors, telling exactly the place where you are getting errors.

Comment: I am getting error at line no. 82 which from which code u sent me and the error is  >"Package org.apache.commons.io does not exists.
internal error cannot instantiate paragraph float at com.itext.pdf.paragraph to ()".........................................................................


and error is on this line.




pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));

Comment: You have to download `org.apache.commons` jar and add it to the build path.

Comment: What is exact name of jar file.. is it apache-commons.jar

Comment: i downloaded it and built it to the path but it didnt work same error as it was earlier ..

Comment: I think there must another Jar file. what do u think?

Comment: hey dude i had tried commons-io.jar and its working..

Comment: friend now java class is working . i call class's main function in a jsp page but no pdf is generated.. may u tel me where the problem is?

Comment: @NoobUnChained please tel me what should i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sample.pdfconvertor;       
import com.lowagie.text.Document;    
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;    
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
public class PDFConversion    
{    
 /**   
  * This method is used to convert the given file to a PDF format   
  * @param inputFile - Name and the path of the file   
  * @param outputFile - Name and the path where the PDF file to be saved   
  * @param isPictureFile   
  */   

  private void createPdf(String inputFile, String outputFile, boolean isPictureFile)    
  {    
   /**   
    * Set the page size for the image   
    */   
     Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(2780, 2525);    
     Document pdfDocument = new Document(pageSize);    
     String pdfFilePath = outputFile;    

     try    
     {    
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath);    

       PdfWriter writer = null;    

       writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, fileOutputStream);    

       writer.open();    

       pdfDocument.open();    

       /**   
        * Proceed if the file given is a picture file   
       */   

       if (isPictureFile)    
       {    
          pdfDocument.add(com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(inputFile));    
       }    

       /**  
        * Proceed if the file given is (.txt,.html,.doc etc)   
        */   

      else      
      {    
          File file = new File(inputFile);    
         pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));    

      }    

      pdfDocument.close();    

      writer.close();    
  }    
  catch (Exception exception)    
  {    
     System.out.println("Document Exception!" + exception);    
  }    

 }     


 public static void main(String args[])    
 {    

   PDFConversion pdfConversion = new PDFConversion();    

  //pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/shunmuga/tajmahal.jpg", "C:/shunmuga/tajmahal.pdf", true);    


  // For other files    

  pdfConversion.createPdf("a.html","sample.pdf", false);    

}
```